# Installation of clang not correct, always “segmentation fault”

Tags: c++, clang

I have recently switched to ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS) and have tried installing clang (and clang++). I did it with:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

and can find clang and clang++ in /usr/bin

When I try to compile any program, I get a "segmentation fault". (I did compile a simple program that prints "hello" with g++ and it worked). The command I used was:

```
clang++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

Can anybody help me?

I've tried deinstalling and reinstalling it, but nothing works so far.

(For reference, the code is:

```
#include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        std::cout << "Hello\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

)

If that's any help, `ldd which clang++` outputs the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc09b2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f30f14ea000)
libclang-cpp.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/libclang-cpp.so.10 (0x00007f30edfcc000)
libLLVM-10.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1 (0x00007f30e9938000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f30e9757000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f30e9608000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f30e95ed000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f30e93f9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f30f1532000)
libLLVMCoroutines.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMCoroutines.so.10 (0x00007f30e93c1000)
libLLVMCoverage.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMCoverage.so.10 (0x00007f30e9391000)
libLLVMFrontendOpenMP.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMFrontendOpenMP.so.10 (0x00007f30e937c000)
libLLVMLTO.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMLTO.so.10 (0x00007f30e9308000)
libLLVMObjCARCOpts.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMObjCARCOpts.so.10 (0x00007f30e92d6000)
libLLVMPasses.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMPasses.so.10 (0x00007f30e9185000)
libLLVMOption.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMOption.so.10 (0x00007f30e9171000)
libLLVMipo.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMipo.so.10 (0x00007f30e8f57000)
libLLVMIRReader.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMIRReader.so.10 (0x00007f30e8f4d000)
libLLVMMCJIT.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMMCJIT.so.10 (0x00007f30e8f3a000)
libLLVMInstrumentation.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMInstrumentation.so.10 (0x00007f30e8dfe000)
libLLVMLinker.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMLinker.so.10 (0x00007f30e8dd4000)
libLLVMBitWriter.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMBitWriter.so.10 (0x00007f30e8d84000)
libLLVMScalarOpts.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.so.10 (0x00007f30e89eb000)
libLLVMInstCombine.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMInstCombine.so.10 (0x00007f30e8891000)
libLLVMTransformUtils.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.so.10 (0x00007f30e8664000)
libLLVMExecutionEngine.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMExecutionEngine.so.10 (0x00007f30e8639000)
libLLVMTarget.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMTarget.so.10 (0x00007f30e8626000)
libLLVMAnalysis.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMAnalysis.so.10 (0x00007f30e81be000)
libLLVMProfileData.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMProfileData.so.10 (0x00007f30e813b000)
libLLVMObject.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMObject.so.10 (0x00007f30e8004000)
libLLVMMCParser.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMMCParser.so.10 (0x00007f30e7fa9000)
libLLVMMC.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMMC.so.10 (0x00007f30e7ebe000)
libLLVMBitReader.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMBitReader.so.10 (0x00007f30e7e32000)
libLLVMCore.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMCore.so.10 (0x00007f30e7adb000)
libLLVMBitstreamReader.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMBitstreamReader.so.10 (0x00007f30e7ac3000)
libLLVMSupport.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/libLLVMSupport.so.10 (0x00007f30e7890000)
libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f30e7884000)
libedit.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x00007f30e784a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f30e782e000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f30e7823000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f30e781d000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f30e77ed000)
libLLVMCodeGen.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMCodeGen.so.10 (0x00007f30e7250000)
libLLVMAggressiveInstCombine.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMAggressiveInstCombine.so.10 (0x00007f30e7237000)
libLLVMVectorize.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMVectorize.so.10 (0x00007f30e7138000)
libLLVMAsmParser.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMAsmParser.so.10 (0x00007f30e70b3000)
libLLVMRuntimeDyld.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.so.10 (0x00007f30e701e000)
libLLVMBinaryFormat.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.so.10 (0x00007f30e6ff9000)
libLLVMTextAPI.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMTextAPI.so.10 (0x00007f30e6fc1000)
libLLVMRemarks.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMRemarks.so.10 (0x00007f30e6f7f000)
libz3.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz3.so.4 (0x00007f30e59df000)
libLLVMDemangle.so.10 => /usr/local/llvm-10/lib/../lib/../lib/libLLVMDemangle.so.10 (0x00007f30e5994000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f30e597a000)
```

Comment: It appears to be loading a bunch of llvm-10 libs in `/usr/local` - which I would not expect for anything installed via `apt`. Did you previously attempt to install clang and/or llvm by another method?

Comment: @steeldriver i did (tried too many things probably), I think I downloaded and installed llvm via git. it's all probably just a mess ':D i tried deinstalling too, but I think some stuff always remains and doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the comments, you have some cruft in `/usr/local`, and for some reason (wrong environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or such?) it seems they get picked before/instead of the official ones under `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`.

Use `ldd(1)` to find out what libraries your `/usr/bin/clang` is trying to load.

You say you tried to install `clang` from git, that will install under `/usr/local/` by default. Use `locate(1)` or `find(1)` to look up the offending files (the error message points at plenty suspects), check if the file belongs to something important/is a file installed by your package manager (I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, some Debian person might provide the incantation to do so), remove (or stash away at e.g. `/var/tmp/usr/local/...` to keep track of the original places) and try again.